# How to find the Javascript library version used in a Website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, web

I am trying to find the javascript library version used in popular websites.

Using phantomjs.exe I was able to find that information for jquery.  But I don't know how to extend it for other Javascript libaries like angular,ninject, mochajs, reactjs and nodejs

Here is the link to phanotomjs.exe in http://phantomjs.org/download.html

I am attaching the file that I use for jquery.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;
 
if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: libdetect.js url');
    phantom.exit(1);
}
 
page.settings.loadImages = false;
address = system.args[1];
console.log('Loading', address, '...');
 
page.open(address, function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('ERROR: Unable to load', address);
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function () {
      var jQueryVersion;
      jQueryVersion = page.evaluate(function () {
        return (typeof jQuery === 'function') ? jQuery.fn.jquery : undefined;
      });
      if (jQueryVersion) {
        console.log('jQuery', jQueryVersion);
      } else {
        console.log('This site does not use jQuery.');
      }
      phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Usually the version number is at the top of the file in a comment. Are you asking for a way to write a script which does this, or are you asking how to find the version number manually?

Comment: @4castle : I want to do that via a script/command and not manually

Answer (score 0):

For `angularjs` version use

```
angular.version
```

For `nodejs` version use

```
node -v
```

Or

```
node --version
```